# Javascript: Making divs hold state of display='block' when user clicks BACK button in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a few divs on a form that are hidden by default (style="display:none;"). When the user clicks a certain radio button, an onclick event executes and exposes the divs. The user is then taken to a review page upon form submit that shows him any errors. If there are any, he clicks the BACK button on his browser to go back to the form and correct them. Caching is enabled so that all of his form contents are there. The problem is, since the form is looking for an onclick event, all of the previously exposed divs are hidden again. Is there any way to make sure they stay exposed when the user clicks back to the form from the review page? I thought a document.ready function would do it, but no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Yair mentioned, you can use cookies. It cannot be done with pure JS. However, you can also use PHP.

Before the user is transferred to the second page, have JS scan the `divs` in question, and find which ones are visible. (I'm assuming they all have individual IDs). Store these IDs in a comma-delimited string, or array, and send it as a _POST or _GET to the new page.

Have PHP store it as a hidden value somewhere. You could use a hidden input, or a data-x on something ... as long as it's there.

Have JS on that page that watches for the back click, stops it, and then redirects the user to the previous page, and sends the string or array back to it. Have PHP on that page print it as a JS value, and have JS on pageload show all divs with matching IDs.

Comment: There is no "answer above" in Stack overflow. The answer's position on the page changes with voting and acceptance and the answer to which you refer might be deleted. Please try to avoid relative references to other answers because these tend to break. I would edit your post to remove the reference but there are not 3 answers to which you might have been referring. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to make sure they stay exposed when the user clicks
>   back to the form from the review page? I thought a document.ready
>   function would do it, but no joy.

You can use cookies in order to manage state in a web-browser. Cookies will help you save the desired user's state.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies or localStorage if you aim for only modern browsers:

[localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Comment: Including the explanation here in the answer would be much better, rather than linking to a place where it may disappear any time.

Answer (score 0):

All javascript code is reinitialized on browser reload. You cannot identify whether the user comes back through the browser.

You can use cookies or local storage to save a value when initial display happens and show/hide the div later on document.ready.